# How can I horizontally scroll through my HTML table?

Tags: html, css

Thanks so much for your help. I hoped the code below would give me a table that can be scrolled horizontally, but instead it cuts off the left side of the table. I'll give a screenshot below. I tried using different overflow tags with no luck (including overflow:auto) - all I managed to do was get a greyed out scroll bar:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myTable {
        font-size: 5em;
        overflow: visible;
        overflow: scroll;
        font-style: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <div id="myTable"><table border="1" align="right"><tr>
        <th>SomeHeaderX</th><th>SomeHeaderyY</th><th>SomeHeaderZ</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th></tr><tr><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td></tr></table></div>
</p></body>
</html>
```

Here's the output I'm getting:

[image: TableOutput]

Any help on getting this table or even whole page to be scrollable would be great.

Thanks again.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1h97u08a/)

Comment: you can't set a css property more than once...the original one will get overwritten (overflow : scroll is the end value)...therefore the content is clipped and the content should always have a scrollabar...but you need to have a width

Comment: also you shouldn't style elements with html attributes...should resort to css for that

Comment: My first response was 'very painfully', but it seems you got a better answer. :) If you only want to scroll from side to side you may want to change your overflow to overflow-x.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/1h97u08a/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the align right in your table. It seems to fix it...

```
...
    <div id="myTable"><table border="1"><tr>
...
```

Edit: Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1h97u08a/1/) of it working

Answer (score 2):

Give the wrapper a width:

```
#myTable {
        font-size: 5em;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        font-style: bold;
        width:500px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="myTable">
    <table border="1"><tr>
        <th>SomeHeaderX</th><th>SomeHeaderyY</th><th>SomeHeaderZ</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th><th>SomeHeaderABC</th>
        <th>SomeHeaderABC</th></tr><tr><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td><td>DataABC</td>
            <td>DataABC</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myTable{overflow:auto}
```

Basically: remove that `p`, remove that `align` (and you should remove the border) and use pure CSS

Answer (score 0):

HTML changes

```
border="1" align="right"
```

CSS changes

```
overflow: auto;
width : 300px;
```

If you want to add a border or align the table right use css not html

http://jsfiddle.net/8zh33mb9/